# Does it safety allow to inserting images from foreign servers?

Tags: javascript, php, security

I writing imageboard, I don't know about safety of allowing users posting/inserting images from foreign servers. Is it ok? What possible security problems may it bring?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean hot linking directly to images hosted on another server, rather than uploading them to your server from a remote server?

There is no security risk from allowing your users to hotlink directly to a remote image (as long as your script does not copy the image to your server) as it will be rendered by the remote server and not your own.

If they are however uploading them to your server from a remote server then it does pose a risk, but no more than uploading them from their own harddrive.

Read more on protecting yourself from malicious code disguised as an image: http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/67-PHP-security-exploit-with-GIF-images.html

Comment: But may be some security reasons for other users? Like posting exploits etc. Only GIF have a security issues?

Comment: No it is not just gif. Jpg/png are equally affected. You'll need to read up on how to protect from them. As far as the security reasons for other users go, there shouldn't be any problems. As long as your script just uses <img> tags then you should be fine. The only thing somebody could really do would be to post offensive images or some irritatingly large image that would take a long time to load.